# Promise reject doesn't propagate the error correctly

Tags: javascript, typescript, error-handling, promise

I receive a complex object, let's say it will look like this:

```
complexObject: {
    fruits: string[],
    vegetables: string[],
    milk: [] | [{
        expirationDate: string,
        quantity: string
    }]
}
```

So, the logic is, that when I receive an empty object (`milk` will be just `[]`), the `verifyObject` method will return undefined (the further logic is more complex and has to receive undefined...); the same case will be when the method will be called with an empty/undefined object.

The only verification, for the milk, should be like this:
If we have milk, then it needs to have both `quantity` and `expirationDate`, else it should return false.
The problem is, that when I send an object like this:

```
{
    'fruits': ['apples', 'bananas'],
    'vegetables': ['tomatoes'],
    'milk': [{
        'quantity': '10'
    }]
}
```

in the `checkAndAssign` method it will see, the error, print the `console.log`, but it won't stop there and it will add the object to the `result`.
Also, in the `verifyObject` method, it will enter catch block, but upper it won't throw the error and it will resolve the promise instead, returning the result...

I want to stop the execution when I receive a wrong message and propagate the error...

This is the code:

```
verifyObject(complexObject) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const result = {};
        const propertiesEnum = ['fruits', 'vegetables', 'milk'];

        if (!complexObject) {
            resolve({ result: undefined });
        } else {
            this.checkAndAssign(complexObject, result)
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log('enter error');
                    reject({ message: err });
                })
            if (!Object.keys(result).length) {
                console.log('resolve with undefined');
                resolve({ result: undefined });
            }
            console.log('resolve good');
            resolve({ result });
        }

    })
}

private checkAndAssign(complexObject, result) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        for (const property of complexObject) {
            if(complexObject[property] && Object.keys(complexObject[property]).length)
            if(property === 'milk' && this.verifyMilk(complexObject[property]) === false) {
                console.log('rejected');
                reject('incomplete');
            }
            Object.assign(result, {[property]: complexObject[property]})
            console.log('result is...:>', result);
        }
        console.log('final result:>', result);
        resolve(result);
    });
}

private verifyMilk(milk:any): boolean {
    for(const item of milk) {
        if(!(item['expirationDate'] && item['quantity'])) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Does `checkPropertyAndAssignValue` do something asynchronous that isn't shown above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `reject` doesn't terminate the function you call it from. `reject` is just a normal function call. Once the call is complete, the function calling it continues.

If you don't want that, use `return`:

```
private checkPropertyAndAssignValue(complexObject, result) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        for (const property of complexObject) {
            if(complexObject[property] && Object.keys(complexObject[property]).length)
            if(property === 'milk' && this.verifyMilk(complexObject[property]) === false) {
                console.log('rejected');
                reject('incomplete');
                return; // <================================================ here
            }
            Object.assign(result, {[property]: complexObject[property]})
            console.log('result is...:>', result);
        }
        console.log('final result:>', result);
        resolve(result);
    });
}
```

Then `verifyObject` needs to wait for the fulfillment of the promise from `checkPropertyAndAssignValue`. `verifyObject`'s code falls prey to the *explicit promise creation anti-pattern*: It shoudln't use `new Promise`, because it already has a promise from `checkPropertyAndAssignValue`. Avoiding the anti-pattern also helps avoid this error:

```
verifyObject(complexObject) {
    const result = {};
    const propertiesEnum = ['fruits', 'vegetables', 'milk'];

    if (!complexObject) {
        return Promise.resolve({ result: undefined });
    }

    return this.checkPropertyAndAssignValue(complexObject, result)
        .then(() => {
            if (!Object.keys(result).length) {
                console.log('resolve with undefined');
                return { result: undefined };
            }
            console.log('resolve good');
            return { result };
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log('enter error');
            throw { message: err }; // *** Will get caught by the promise mechanism and turned into rejection
        });
}
```

---

As an alternative: If you're writing this code for modern environments, you may find `async` functions and `await` to be more familiar, since they use the same constructs (`throw`, `try`, `catch`) that you're used to from synchronous code. For example:

```
async verifyObject(complexObject) {
    const result = {};
    const propertiesEnum = ['fruits', 'vegetables', 'milk'];

    if (!complexObject) {
        return { result: undefined };
    }

    try {
        await this.checkPropertyAndAssignValue(complexObject, result);
//      ^^^^^−−−−− waits for the promise to settle
        if (!Object.keys(result).length) {
            console.log('return undefined');
            return { result: undefined };
        }
        console.log('return good');
        return { result };
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('enter error');
        throw { message: err }; // *** FWIW, suggest making all rejections Error instances
                                // (even when using promises directly)
    }
}

private async checkPropertyAndAssignValue(complexObject, result) {
    // *** Note: This used to return a promise but didn't seem to have any asynchronous
    //     code in it. I've made it an `async` function, so if it's using something
    //     that returns a promise that you haven't shown, include `await` when getting
    //     its result.
    for (const property of complexObject) {
        if(complexObject[property] && Object.keys(complexObject[property]).length)
        if(property === 'milk' && this.verifyMilk(complexObject[property]) === false) {
            throw 'incomplete'; // *** FWIW, suggest making all rejections Error instances
                                // (even when using promises directly)
        }
        Object.assign(result, {[property]: complexObject[property]})
        console.log('result is...:>', result);
    }
    console.log('final result:>', result);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Let's say I can't use async-await or throw...
I've tried with only adding the return in the checkPropertyAndAssignValue method and it won't add the milk (as it's wrong), but in `verifyObject` it will return the object and then enter the catch block...
So `verifyObject` will return a value and will not propagate the error

Comment: @rocko - Yeah, `verifyObject` needs to use a `then` handler. I'll update. (Fun note: That issue was automatically fixed using an `async` function. That's part of their power.)

Comment: @rocko - I've updated to show how to fix `verifyObject`. :-) But please do answer my question in a comment on the question.

Comment: Apparently a `then` handler fixed all that was left :)
I didn't even see that one... maybe it's just because of the tiredness...
Anyway, thank you a million times!! :D